# What is the dimension of $\mathrm{End}_A(E)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional real unital algebra and $E$ an $A$-module. Since $A$ is unital, $E$ obtains a real vector space structure. We assume that $E$ is finite-dimensional. $\mathrm{End}_A(E)\subset\mathrm{End}(E)$ is defined in the obvious way, i.e. $f\in \mathrm{End}_A(E)$ if and only if$$\forall (a,x)\in A\times E:a\cdot f(x)=f(a\cdot x).$$

That being said, can we express the dimension of $\mathrm{End}_A(E)$ in terms of the dimension of $A$ and $E$? I would like to check whether there can be a vector space isomorphism$$A\otimes \mathrm{End}_A(E)\to\mathrm{End}(E).$$

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez So you are saying that we can find two pairs $(A,E)$ and $(A',E')$ s.t. $\dim A=\dim A'$ and $\dim E=\dim E'$, but $\dim \mathrm{End}_A(E)\neq \dim \mathrm{End}_{A'}(E')$?

Comment: @Filippo Assume $k$ is characteristic $0$ and algebraically closed. Consider the case when $A = kG$ for some finite non-abelian group $G$. Let $E$ be a simple $A$-module of dimension $>1$ and let $E'$ be the direct sum of $\dim E$ many trivial modules. Then $\dim E = \dim E'$ but $\dim \text{End}_A(E) = 1$ while $\dim \text{End}_A(E') = \dim \text{End}_k(E') = \dim(E)^2 > 1$.